# Rendering VF page as PDF

Tags: pdf, custom

I'm a beginner. Help me with this problem statement.

I have to create a custom button on opportunity object which will redirect user to a VF page which will populate some opportunity fields and a table showing related opportunity product details in PDF form.
Opportunity fields to populate-
a)  Opportunity Name
b)  Parent Account Name
c)  Stage
d)  Type

Comment: Post your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: or refer this [Render as PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm)

Comment: Refer this "Get Started with Visualforce"  trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/units/visualforce_intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code : -

```
[![<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" renderAs="PDF">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Opportunity Name    : </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Parent Account Name    : </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Account.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Stage     : </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Type     : </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Type}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock><br/><br/>



    </apex:form> 
    <apex:relatedList list="OpportunityLineItems" />    
</apex:page>][1]][1]
```

Comment: how to create a table showing related opportunity product details

Comment: just use this : <apex:relatedList list="OpportunityLineItems" />

Comment: how to create a validation rule for "type" field mandatory in account?

Comment: For type related query pleas raise another question.